# Generic class object create and set the value to variables of that generic class, object of the generic add to arrayList

Tags: generics, kotlin

[My code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keMsv.png)I'm writing a class which will give the arrayList of generics, eg: a inline function will take the class name and the output comes as arrayList of that generic class. please help me with this Thanks.

I have a inline function in which creating the generic class instance, and a generic class arrayList, i am trying to add that object of the generic class into arrayList and its working but I am not able to set values to that generic class variables and create instance of that class and add to the arrayList.

"Please check the Code in Image, In code block because of syntax correction  some line modified."

// Inline function

inline fun  modelClass(Val: (va: ArrayList) -> Unit) {

```
       // instance of generic class
        var obj = T::class.java.newInstance()

       // how to set values to the variable of "obj" ?

        // generic arrayList 
        var list = ArrayList<T>()

        // adding object to the list
        list.add(obj)
        list.add(obj)

        Val(list)
}
```

//===================================================================

// call method

```
modelClass<testClass> {
        // printing the values of list
        it.forEach { it ->
            Log.d("ModelClass", "ModelClass - " + it.firstName)
        }
    }
```

//===================================================================

// model class for reference

class testClass {

```
var firstName : String = "hi"
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        field = value
    }
```

}

how to add the variable values to the obj as shown in code

"Only getting the default value of variable"

Output :-

ModelClass - hi

Comment: Note that this will probably be a lot easier if you skip the reflection entirely and pass in a refactory, calling `modelClass(::T)` instead of `modelClass<T>()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for quick response, can you show me how to do it by code.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution,

inline fun modelClass(Val: (va: ArrayList) -> Unit) {

```
   // generic arrayList 
   var list = ArrayList<T>()

   var jacksonObjectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()

   var map = WeakHashMap<String, String>()
   map["key"] = "value"

   var obj = jacksonObjectMapper.convertValue(map, T::class.java)

    // adding object to the list
    list.add(obj)

    Val(list)
```

}